# Advantages of Cassandra db over Mongo db

Tags: mongodb, cassandra, nosql

i am new to NoSql database  we have read a bit about MongoDB and Cassandra, though we have absolutely no experience with either.

We want to start a project with following functionality given below which Database is suitable for our Requirement

1. Geo location storage and Retrieving

2.Dynamic Form Data Storage and Retrieving

3.Large Amount of Json Data Storage

In which seniors We Prefer MongoDB and Cassandra

So basically, which NoSQL database do you guys recommend for our use?

Best Regards,
Sagar

Comment: Any question asking this type of subject tends to get subjective and opinionated as such is not a good fit for SO I am afraid

Comment: I would recommend you to set up a test installation of both and play around a bit with each of them to find out which one is most suitable for **your** approach to **your** project. By the way, when JSON is an explicit requirement, you should also give CouchDB a try, because JSON is its native data format.

Answer (score 3):

As @sammaye states, these kind of questions can bring some subjective and not useful answers. So, in order to be useful I will try to show some objectives advantages/disadvantages and capabilities of each quoted databases:

**Cassandra**:

- A column based database (some kind of multi-value hashtable). In order to leverage the full capabilities and power of Cassandra you have to create your data model with a key based access in mind. Thus, using Cassandra for complex/rich data models can become very hard.
- Due to its very raw data structures, handling geospatial data is nearly impossible (according to my knowledge, the only one who used Cassandra for geospatial data is [SimpleGeo](http://www.simplegeo.com) with [Mike Malone](https://twitter.com/mjmalone) after two years of development)
- Its offered data structures does not include JSON. So, using it to manipulate large amount of JSON data can also be hard.

**MongoDB**:

- A document based database (simple JSON data). Complex data can be modelled very easily because of the rich semantic of JSON documents.
- Geospatial data [is supported natively](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/).

In summary, MongoDB seems to fit your need.

Remark: I'm using both databases in every day work and my personal thought is that you have to use each database for what it is made for. Cassandra has a large set of advantages over MongoDB but in very special domains (and vice versa).

Comment: thanks fsehat for giving your suggestion

Comment: Cassandra actually excels at "geospacial location storage and retrieval" and lots of people use it for this purpose - especially in mobile telecom. What Cassandra doesn't do natively are all the distance calculations, polygon math, etc. that a full GIS solution provides. So it really depends on if you only need storage and retrieval of coordinates, or if you are looking for your database to provide more functionality.

Comment: You are right. If you want to store geospatial information (raw ones), Cassandra does the job. However, common use cases include something like retrieving geospatial points from the database and filtering them  by their distances from a given point; and this kind of queries are nearly impossible with Cassandra.